# Stripe payouts to clients java

Tags: java, stripe-payments

Does stripe have some feature for atleast one of those flows?

1. User top ups wallet balance, he buys some product and money goes to merchant, merchant will withdraw his money to his bank account(automatically)
2. User top ups wallet balance, he buys some product and money goes to merchant, merchant would create some kind of intent on stripe api, which would have to be accepted by staff, after it gots accepted money goes to merchants bank account

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can review the payment method types Stripe's API offers and the ways you can use them here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/integration-options#payment-method-product-support

To accomplish something like you're asking you'd use a third party wallet like   those available here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/wallets